# Choosing a web app framework to replace VB6 and Access applications

Tags: web-applications, vba, vb6, vb6-migration, database-migration

I am currently working at a large firm which has quite a lot of Access databases. They already have SQL Server in place. Now it's my task to migrate the databases and eventually the applications as well. All of them written in Visual Basic 6. I work with 2 other people who know only VB6 and are not really eager to learn anything else. Something else to keep in mind is that rapid development in this case is more important than robustness. Especially when it comes to reporting capabilities. I have a strong background in Java/Spring/Hibernate but I don't really think that's such a good choice, since development time in java apps is generally longer than other and it's kind of a stretch from VB6 for the others to learn. All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What's the motivation for switching from VB6? Is it to improve development speed (and do bear in mind the learning curve, especially for your 2 colleagues)? Is it because you're worried about support possibly ending for the VB6 runtime? Is it to make it easier to recruit developers in future? There are good reasons for wanting to switch, just be clear in your own mind about what they are & be clear with your managers.

Comment: The reason is that there is too much legacy code involved. Some of these programs are in the running for 12 years already.The age isn't not my primary concern, but still an indication. Because the functionality of these apps has shifted over the years. Some databases should be consolidated and duplicate data deleted. They have been handed down a couple of times, so there's a lot of messy code. And all of them are hogging the network.  Querying a couple large linked tables over the network is just ridiculous. Things that takes 15 seconds in SQL Server takes 12 minutes in Access.

Answer (score 5):

I’m in almost the same situation. I started out with 5 or so “pure” access applications i.e. the front end was access and the back end was JET. What I did was to use a 2 step process. First I migrated the data into a SQL server whilst keeping the front end the same.

Once I was happy with that I started converting one application at a time to either an asp.net web app or a vb.net client app depending on what was the best fit.

For the reporting I used the excellent report builder 3.0 that comes with SQL server 2008R2.

The jump from VBA to vb.net is still a change especially if you are used to using DAO/ADO for data access as ADO.net is quite a different beast but once you get your head round it things are quite simple

Well that’s my story of what I went through in your situation, hope it helps

EDIT: This is some of the selection process I go through.

It would depend on who is going to be using it and the feature set that is required.

There are two examples I can tell you about.

The first is an application called “Breach Light” it is used to allow everybody (400 users) to log breaches in process they come across. Its 3 simple data capture forms used infrequently by a large user base so it is going to be a web app so I get the benefits of no install and easy update and the downsides don’t matter so much.

The second on is a rich client used by 20 or so people that does all of the call forecasting etc. That one is going to be a vb.net desktop app to allow for a better user experience.

As with everything its horses for courses, it does annoy me when people say “web apps for everything” or “I hate web apps, thick clients for all!”. Use the correct tool for the correct task

Comment: Thanks for the input. But when you say you choose between a asp.net web app or a vb.net client app, on what did that depend?

Comment: @Arne W, I have added some extra points to my answer to answer your question

Comment: With the Edit, I'd upvote this ten times if I could. Horses for Courses!

Comment: I'm voting this one up. I did a similar switch of a large application from VB6 to ASP.net and VB.net and it went smoothly. The difference between VB6 and VB.net tends to be exaggerated, especially if, like me, you tend to work with an open reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the situation of trying to continue supporting VB6 code into the future, I would strongly recommend looking at REAL Studio (formerly REALBasic) http://www.realsoftware.com/

It's a really excellent package that is very compatible with VB6 - especially in combination with the Windows Functionality Suite: http://www.arbpmembers.org/windows-functionality-suite

Other libraries add massive sets of capabilities: http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/realbasic/plugins.shtml

Many more libraries and controls are listed here: http://www.rbgarage.arbpmembers.org/rbg/

Additionally I believe it has COM interop so you should be able to keep using any custom COM controls you have purchased.

Finally, RB can now be deployed to Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, and even as a stand-alone web application server. It's a very flexible platform, would be easy for VB6 programmers to convert to, and has a relatively large community of developers.

I ported a relatively complex VB6 application (actually a text adventure game engine originally written in VB3) to REALBasic in an afternoon with minimal trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the easiest to migrate to VB.NET & ASP.NET/WEB FORMS, if you take into account the current VB6 developers.
VB.NET is not completly the same as VB6, but it's closer than java.
Also, asp.net web-forms follows the winforms model, so that would be easier to.
But they will have a learning curve grasping .net and webdevelopment in general.
If they use Access, would the also using VBA?

Or hire new developers and use what you are comfortable with :)
Because developers not eager to learn new things are selling themselves short.

Comment: It's possible that these 2 colleagues aren't very curious about development but have excellent business knowledge. People like that *can* be very useful, although you might try to find a way of working that prevents them dictating the technology choices.